# Parsing key-value pairs for sorting in clojure

Tags: parsing, sorting, clojure, functional-programming, hashmap

I want to sort a given sequence of maps by using one of the keys, Cost:

```
({:Date "2012-12-01", :Cost "11.23"} {:Date "2012-12-02", :Cost "25.68"} {:Date "2012-12-03", :Cost "20.55"} {:Date "2012-12-04", :Cost "50.22"})
```

However, I don't want to do the sort while the value for :Cost is a string.  I initially tried by using the (sort-by) function using the key :Cost but the sort is doing string comparisons instead of double comparisons. Is there a way to parse the values for :Cost from strings to doubles in a sequence of maps?  I'm relatively new to Clojure and functional programming and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Double/parseDouble`:

```
(sort-by #(Double/parseDouble (:Cost %)) input-list)
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! This works like a charm and does exactly what I need. Much thanks. :)